# unexpected token while runing gaphql server

Tags: graphql-js

i runing my graphql server via terminal,, but when i am runing

```
$node server
```

geeting error like this

```
/home/bimoan/Desktop/bibitnomic-api/server.js:3
var { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

this is my server.js

```
 var express = require("express");
    var express_graphql = require("express-graphql");
    var { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
    // GraphQL schema
    var schema = buildSchema(`
        type Query {
            message: String,
            User: String
        }
    `);
    // Root resolver
    var root = {
      message: () => "Hello World!",
      User: () => " Bimo ANugrah"
    };
    // Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint
    var app = express();
    app.use(
      "/graphql",
      express_graphql({
        schema: schema,
        rootValue: root,
        graphiql: true
      })
    );
    app.listen(4000, () =>
      console.log("Express GraphQL Server Now Running On localhost:4000/graphql")
    );
```

where my code is wrong ??
I was not change anything what and why this can happen? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of node are you using? Object destructuring wasn't supported until 6.4.0 or so

Comment: This is how you require graphql `const graphql = require('graphql');` and this is how you require express graphql `const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');`

Comment: @daniel Care to explain why? The documentation says otherwise.

Comment: @n0rd, this is a 2 year old thread and I have not worked on a GraphQL project since then, so the documentation may have been updated. I would like to do another GraphQL project in the future, but probably will not happen for another year.

Comment: @Daniel Totally understandable. Thanks for getting back to me.